# How do I save keypad settings in Bootcamp?

Tags: boot-camp

I have Windows 8 running on my MacBook Pro using Boot camp and everything is fine apart from the fact I have to change the settings for the touchpad every time I log in.

Is there a way to save the settings?

Thanks